# Cannot use t"_Schema" from another module or realm. Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm getting this graphql instance error. How should I fix it?

I've tried adding the following in package.json but it produce the same error.

"resolutions": {
  "graphql": "0.13.0"
}

Cannot use t"_Schema" from another module or realm. Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version installed.
[Screenshot of error is attached here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUP9F.jpg)